# How to compare frequency distributions between 3 groups

Tags: repeated-measures, multinomial-distribution

I have characterized cells into 6 categories and want to compare the percent distribution of the different categories at 3 time points. Once I figure that out, I actually have additional treatment groups as well. What is the appropriate statistical test for comparing the frequency distribution between the 3 timepoints? Also, I am not a programmer, but hoping to do this in GraphPad.

Comment: Is it accurate to describe your data as essentially a 6-row by 3 column contingency table?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I've just only worked with x 2 contingency tables...

Comment: What is the null hypothesis? That the three distributions are equal, but otherwise unspecified?